# PHP Cannot exit hexdec()

Tags: php, hex

I've been struggling with this quite a bit; exiting hexdec in PHP. For some reason, `echo`'ing the function works, but refuses to output when exited.

```
$term = '5.05';
$term = hexdec(str_replace('.', '', $term) . '0000');
echo $term; // works, outputs 84213760

$term = '5.05';
$term = hexdec(str_replace('.', '', $term) . '0000');
exit($term); // outputs nothing, same goes for return
```

Also it seems it can `exit` output large numbers, for example `5.055555555555` as input value. Does anyone know why this is happening? Why does it not output when exited?

Comment: From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual [**exit**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> **status**
>
> If status is a string, this function prints the status just
>   before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

So it must be a string to output:

```
exit((string)$term);
```

Nowhere in the manual for [**return**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) does it mention outputting:

> returns program control to the calling module.

Comment: I see. Thank you, that answers my question!